# What is the Commodore 64C "France version" and why does it need a beefy resistor?

Tags: commodore-64, power, printed-circuit-board

While perusing the [schematics](http://www.zimmers.net/anonftp/pub/cbm/schematics/computers/c64/250469-rev.B-right-corrected.png) for the [Commodore 64C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_64#Commodore_64C) (titled *COMMODORE-64 B/NE*) I came across a suspicious section of the power supply: The unregulated "9V" is connected to the completely separate +5V with a 20 Ohm resistor, annotated with the following:

> [7] FRANCE VERSION
> R2: 20Ω RESISTOR & C63: 2200 µF CAPACITOR REQUIRED

**What is this "France version" and why does it require special care?**

I suppose a follow-up question is if this was ever implemented.

Here is the relevant section of the schematics:

[image: Relevant section of the Commodore 64 schematic]

This seems like a kludge for anyone into electronics:

- It connects a "dirty" voltage, possibly with a lot of ripple, onto the clean regulated digital voltage through a low impedance.
- As can be seen from the "5W" specification, this will waste a lot of power. "9V UNREG" is normally closer to 12 V, so this can dissipate up to 2.5 watts.
- Pulling that much extra current from the unregulated line will increase the ripple, hence they also need to double the filter capacitor C63.
- The regulated +5V is fed directly from the power supply using a linear regulator, and those are bad at *reducing* the voltage if it exceeds the target level.

Comment: Did the French version of C64 have a SECAM output? Is it related to that?

Comment: @UncleBod that was my first thought as well but reading these schematics I'm completely baffled, it makes no sense and doesn't look like it even touches video output

Comment: @OmarL It does relate to SECAM output and it does touch the video output, just externally to the C64 motherboard - see my answer.

Comment: What, have you never heard of the famous french resistance?

Comment: @rackandboneman Godd*mn.. now I'm temped to write a new question title

Comment: @pipe me too, but for other reasons + other question. AFAIK also USSR used SECAM (And actually France being (the only?) western user. I wonder how many C64s went to the other side of the curtain?

Comment: @Tuomo hardly any C64's went to the USSR, but IIRC a very small number ended up in Poland. SÉCAM was also common in parts of Africa though. I wonder if any C64s ended up there.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As noted in the question, the resistor is there to allow something to consume more current without voltage dropping too much.

But what consumes more current may not visible in the schematics.

France (and a few other countries) used the SECAM colour encoding for analog television. The SECAM encoding is very different from PAL and NTSC, so it was not possible to produce a VIC-II video chip that would directly output a SECAM colour signal, at least not without huge changes to the circuitry that is.

However, since France used the same 625-line 50 Hz TV system as most PAL countries did, a PAL version of the VIC-II could be used as usual, with an extra step afterwards for the color encoding to be converted to SECAM. This was accomplished via an [additional circuit board](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https://www.c64-wiki.de/wiki/Procep_SECAM) inside the C64 manufactured by Procep, which takes in composite video or the separate luma and chroma signals near the AV connector, and decodes the color signals.

There have supposedly been two versions of these adapter boards, one version that decodes the PAL signal to RGB for connecting it to a TV via SCART (Peritel) connector, and the other one that decodes the PAL signal to YUV which can be encoded back to SECAM signal.

So most likely the extra resistor and bulk reservoir capacitor are there to allow powering the add-on board which allows connecting the C64 to a French TV. This arrangement allows the system to consume more 5V current, as some portion of the current drawn by 5V circuits is provided by the resistor from the unregulated 9V, so the same 5V regulator can still be used without it heating up too much.

Some people have also speculated that the C64 power supply sold in France was just too weak so they had to modify the C64 to work with it, but that is an unlikely explanation as the context is not seen in the schematics.

Comment: I wanted to improve this answer by linking a photo of the circuit board or schematic for encoding SECAM, but have not found any. Maybe someone here has a French C64c in their possession?

Comment: Added link to translated German C64-Wiki page that describes Procep board...

Comment: Comments should be related to the post; this discussion about the advantages of PAL over NTSC has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129735/discussion-on-answer-by-justme-what-is-the-commodore-64c-france-version-and-wh).

Answer (score -1):

Bigger C63 (2200uF instead of 1000uF) indicates the need to better filter ripple of 9V in France version - probably to fulfill more restrictive EMI/RFI requirements in France. In these days bigger capacitors were (and still are) more expensive and Commodore is known for "cost awareness". R2 is same in France and non France version, but anyway, I don't know why it is there. It's quite a strange design for me.

BTW: (9..12V - 5V)/20Ohm = 200..350mA -> 800..2450mW. Not good, but 2W lost in days when monitor consumes 60W it was not big deal.

Comment: There's no R2 on my non-french Commodore 64C. If it was included in every model why would there be a special note?

Comment: Why R2 is required I am not sure. If 9V UNREG is a low power source of 9V, connecting it to regulated +5V through R2 can also improve ripple filtering - raising +9V will raise +5V and linear regulator will do its work, and so on. But it will only work when +9V sources low current (max few hundred mA?). Instead of two linear regulators (5V and 9V) you ends with one +5V and cheap R2. But it is a terrible design. Commodores thinkin: cheap + terrible? Lets implement it ;-)

Comment: That kind of design relies on a guaranteed minimum current draw. Which NMOS and TTL circuitry has. In a way, a linear regulator isn't functionally more than a very intelligent, self adjusting resistor/rheostat...